# HTML showing a broken image

Tags: html

I know the question has been asked a million times, but I just can't find any explanation to the following issue: I've inserted an image in my code, and when I open the page in my browser, I'm just having a broken link.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Laura Caroline’s Portfolio</title>
  <link href=“/teststyle.css” type=“text/css” rel=“stylesheet”/>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>About me</h1>
  <p><img src=“portrait.jpeg”/></p>
</body>

</html>
```

The photo is in the same folder than the page. I've double checked the name.
I'm on MacOS Sierra (if of any help). Oh, and I'm a beginner :) Any clue about where to look to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check your browser console. Usually F12. Likely `portrait.jpeg` is a dead link. Correct it. Same folder, usually it is adviceable to do `./portrait.jpeg`.

Comment: Are you sure about `“`? I'd use standard `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see make sure it's in the same directory. Try adding './file.jpg'

About the quotation marks they don't really look like the standard ones. So try replacing that with ""

Comment: Thanks all. I've replaced the quotation marks and it worked.